# How to make a reusable function that calls setUserContext? React Hooks useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

So I have 4 components that are all doing the same thing inside an onClick handler.

I have to define this code in every single one of them.

The reason I don't know how to make this reusable is that you cannot call setUserContext inside a regular non-react utility function. I tried creating a hook but you cannot use Hooks as callbacks inside onClick.

What are my options here?

```
  const { userContext, setUserContext } = useContext(UserContext);

  // this goes inside onClick and is defined in like 4 components (too much repetition)
  const favoriteItem = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    setUserContext({ ...userContext, favoriteItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favoriteItems")) });
  }
```

Comment: What is `game`?

Comment: its irrelevant and i removed it @ksav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom hook.

```
const useCustomHook = () => {


const { userContext, setUserContext } = useContext(UserContext);

  const favoriteItem = (event, game) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    setUserContext({ ...userContext, favoriteItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favoriteItems")) });
  }

return { favoriteItem } 
} 


export default useCustomHook;
```

Your component can do this.

```
... 
const { favoriteItem } = useCustomHook() 

return (
<Element onClick={(event) => favoriteItem(event, game)} /> 
) 
...
```

Comment: Just check why we need `game` and what it is doing there. That'll help to cleanup the code as well.

Comment: its irrelevant and i removed it. I need to call this hook inside onClick handler so i dont think your example will work.

Comment: I think it is still relevant you can remove the game as a dependency and call the same click handler from any function. You want a single click function just to not repeat the code right? You can't create a non-react util as you're using the `setContext` in there.

Comment: You don't have to call this hook inside onClick handler. You just have to import this in a component and pass it to the onClick.

Comment: You're moving your repeated code in a separate hook. I've updated the example. You can also create a separate component if the DOM is same and repeated.

Comment: Ok it turns out the game is relevant. How do i pass it in through the onClick?

Comment: Updated the example. If you don't need an event you can remove that but if you need an event then you should pass both. 

Also, If it works consider accepting the answer as well.

Comment: No problem buddy!

Comment: I'd wrap `favoiteItem` method into `useCallback`. Not because of "extra re-render for PureComponent/React.memo" but because we may want that function in `useEffect` - and running effect on each re-render might be suboptimal.